# Как вывести рандомную функцию из всей программы?

Tags: python

У меня в программе есть несколько функций и я хочу при помощи функции sm выводить рандомную функцию из всего списка функций при помощи модуля sys

```
if sys.argv[1] == 'sm':
    sm()
```

Comment: Что значит _"выводить рандомную функцию"_? Возвращать объект случайной функции из списка? Выполнять её? Вернуть её имя?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def func1():
    print(1)

def func2():
    print(2)

def func3():
    print(3)


funcs = [func1, func2, func3]

from random import choice

random_func = choice(funcs)

random_func()
```